# vega-lite: set circle size at start, when you have size change on mouse over

Tags: vega-lite

I have created [this example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-FkaKRfHQAuh4rIyMPR7FaNEVMJ6jRYg7Ym54lZoAy2aBsfU2GhjoI6qakGsNsTzQAF0yUSxvV7fsNAnJApxnOcyV3JcUmJVcNA3Lc6B3PdiQPW03DYbIzFiBxGhjO8HyfF96UPD8vx-Bl-ztQDgI7VAwPSEBR0-TtF0EVNQKrEBGlkNtnFDb0zUuKlWKDJ1aldEABKEzjK3AzQ2DYQRnBwNArWgwQB3ZLIUHQv1YMQANLkEfd-FtHl1CUCktGQL0QFVIlQCMkybDMldLPQYIEBshl7MPfzsmNJRGkEaIez7YyNH1FplMwDD0FkNgEAdcKlDMMhmxMoICJSuwaCJHi6PfaruFtbImDMJAGABNJNOHHS929V96K7QdxLgP1BpaKxIJAB1bGG2xRvTVIgA).

The circle **size grows on mouse hover**. It's what I want.

[image]

But at start, when I open the editor the circles are not `10` in size, but `200`, that it's the on mouse over size. 
How to **have their size `10` at start**?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the following in your size `condition` or check the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-FkaKRfHQAuh4rIyMPR7FaNEVMJ6jRYg7Ym54lZoAy2aBsfU2GhjoI6qakGsNsTzQAF0yUSxvV7fsNAnJApxnOcyV3JcUmJVcNA3Lc6B3PdiQPW03DYbIzFiBxGhjO8HyfF96UPD8vx-Bl-ztQDgI7VAwPSEBR0-TtF0EVNQKrEBGlkNtnFDGkgiTTtSQHaTWMuKlWKDJ1akNbizBPegZSyJApQAHVUx1nRgAxymiOBjPVTUjW4gShM4ysM24zA2DYQRnBwNArWgwQFJsfSVz9WDEADS5BH3fxbR5dQlApLRkC9EBVSJUB-MC+UQttYIEAihlosPILsmNJRGkEaIez7AKNH1FpXR9UL0FkNgEAdQqlDMMhmwUoICLquwaCJHi6PfUbuFyzozCQBgATScCQGHTy929V96K7QdxLgP1tpaKxIJAB1bF22x9vTVIgA). This will first check the length if any selection is made or not.

```
"condition": [
        {
          "test": {
            "and": [
              {"param": "paintbrush"},
              "length(data(\"paintbrush_store\"))"
            ]
          },
          "value": 100
        }
      ]
```

Or you can try this also:

```
condition": {"param": "paintbrush", "empty": false},
```

Comment: It's once again a great reply, thank you. I can't find in the documentation anything that makes me understand how to think about this kind of solution :(

Comment: Just referring other examples can be helpful sometimes. Added an edit in my answer.